# Is using view decorators to handle user permissions bad practice?

Tags: python, django, security

I'm using Django view decorators to check permissions in quite a complex way, and am starting to realize that this might be bad practice.

Given a user's profile is in a certain state, say 'application pending' and so certain views should not be shown to this user but should be shown to users who have 'application complete'. I'm currently using decorators to redirect pending users to the homepage, with a popup telling them their application is still pending.

However, I read on [google's python best practice](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#217-function-and-method-decorators), that decorators should be simple, and not rely on database connections, files, etc.

Does this mean that something such as checking the state of a borrowers application before showing a view is bad practice, and if it is, what is an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text you mention is debatable at best - at least in it's formulation:

> Avoid external dependencies in the decorator itself (e.g. don’t rely on files, sockets, database connections, etc.), since they might not be available when the decorator runs (at import time, perhaps from pydoc or other tools).
>
> (...)
>
> Decorators are a special case of “top level code”

This only applies to the "outer" part of the decorator function, not the code within the wrapper function (usually) returned by the decorator, ie:

```
def mydecorator(func):
    print("""
       this is the outer decorator code 
       and will be executed when the decorator
       is applied (most often - but not necessarily
       - at import time)
       """
       )
       def wrapper(*args, **kw):
           print("""
              this is the inner decorator code     
              which is only executed when the
              decorated function is called,
              so here it's safe to do whatever
              you would do in the decorated function.
              """
              )
              return func(*args, **kw)
      return wrapper
```

IOW, what you're doing (using decorators in views to check whether the user is allowed to access the content) is not only perfectly ok and a canonical example of what decorators are for, but it's even the official way to handle this in Django, cf Davide Pizzolato's answer.

Comment: Thank you, I see how I misread this now. In the case when this logic becomes quite complex, is there a pattern you might recommend to avoid things like `if user.profile.application.is_submitted and not user.profile.contract.signed or user.....` or is the simplest way just to centralise these boolean permission / user state values on the user model itself to maintain DRY principles and so on.

Comment: Sorry but there's no one-size-fits-all answer to the question in your comment so it would need much more context to come with some possible solutions. You may want to consider posting this as a proper question (giving as much context as possible).

Answer (score 3):

In Django use the `user_passes_test` or `permission_required` decorator is the right way to do it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test, permission_required

@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser)
@permission_required('your_perm')
def my_view(request):
    # code
```